# Matlab Boxplot Y-Axis

Tags: matlab, axis, boxplot

How can I plot a boxplot with y-axis which start from 0 to 20?

I used "axis([0 2 0 20])" but the width of the box isn't the same anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to use ylim:

```
ylim([0 20])
```